# Conditional probability of Poisson distribution.

Tags: probability, probability-theory, proof-verification, probability-distributions

> Assume that the traffic, one afternoon at a certain point in time,
>   both in north and southbound, follows a Possion process with
>   intensities $7$ veichles per minute southbound and $3$ veichles per
>   minute northbound.
>
> **a)** What is the probability that under a given minute, a total of exactly $7$ cars pass?
>
> **b)** At a certain moment, what is the probability that the next veichle that passes is southbound?
>
> **c)** Given that a total of exactly $7$ veichles have passed during one minute, what is the conditional CDF for the number of veichles
>   that are southbound?

### Solution:

**a):** Let the $X,Y$ be the number of veicheles that go south and north respectively. Then $X\sim\text{Poi}(7), \ Y\sim\text{Poi}(3)$ and by independence $X+Y\sim\text{Poi}(10).$ So,

$$P(X+Y=7)=\frac{e^{-10}10^7}{7!}=0.09.$$

**b):** Let the time until the next car is seen going south be $T_s\sim\text{exp}(7)$ and let the time until the next car seen is going north be $T_n\sim\text{exp}(3)$. Then we are looking for

$$P(T_s<T_n)=\int_0^{\infty}P(T_n>x)f_{T_s}(x) \ dx = \int_0^{\infty}(1-P(T_n<x))f_{T_s}(x) \ dx = $$

$$=7\int_0^{\infty}e^{-10x} \ dx=\frac{7}{10.}$$

**c)** It follows that

$$P(X=x|X+Y=7)=P(X=x|Y=7-x)=\frac{P(X=x,Y=7-x)}{P(X+Y=7)}=$$

$$=\frac{P(X=x)P(Y=7-x)}{P(X+Y=7)}=\frac{\frac{e^{-7}7^x}{x!}\cdot\frac{e^{-3}3^{7-x}}{(7-x)!}}{\frac{e^{-10}10^7}{7!}}={7\choose x}\left(\frac{7}{10}\right)^x\left(\frac{3}{10}\right)^{7-x}.$$

### Questions:

**1)** In b), first equation line. When $P(T_s<T_n)$ is computed, I don't understand what is happening there. I assume that the law of total proability is involved in the form

> $$P(Y\in B)=\int_{-\infty}^{\infty}P(Y\in B|X=x)fX(x) \ dx. \tag1$$

However I can't make sence of (1) to my problem. The notations are confusing me. In what way for example, is $P(T_s<T_n)$ similar to $P(Y\in B)?$

**2)** In c), the computations seem to be taken out of the thin air. For example, why is this wrong:

$$P(X=x|X+Y=7)=P(X=x|Y=7-x)=\frac{P(X=x,Y=7-x)}{P(Y=7-x)}=P(X=x),$$

by independence. Why can't I also change the $P(X+Y=7)$ to $P(Y=7-x)$ in the denominator like I did in the numerator?

Comment: In (c) do you want cond'l CDF or PDF?

Comment: In c) I would have used the poisson distribution: $$P(X=1|X+Y=1)=\frac{e^{-7}\cdot \frac{7^1}{1!}\cdot e^{-3}\cdot \frac{3^0}{0!}}{e^{-10}\cdot \frac{10^1}{1!}}$$

Comment: @BruceET - It says conditional CDF.

Comment: @callculus - But they are asking for the conditional CDF as a function of $x$. Your answer is for $x=1$.

Comment: @Parseval Sorry, I meant b)

Comment: Yes but in order to do what you've done, one needs c) first and then do b) in your manner.

Comment: @Parseval Not really. At the numerator we have $P(X=1 \cap X+Y=1)=P(X=1 \cap Y=0)$. Since X and Y are independent we get $P(X=1)\cdot P(Y=0)$

Comment: @callculus - You're right. Thank you for the input.

Comment: Not in answer to your questions, but (a) is essentially about the sum of independent Poissons being Poisson with a rate equal to the sums of the original rates $Pois(\lambda+\mu)$; (b) and (c) are about binomial distributions $Bin\left(1,\frac{\lambda}{\lambda+\mu}\right)$ and  $Bin\left(7,\frac{\lambda}{\lambda+\mu}\right)$